# Link directly to public HTML folder in href inside a Laravel/Blade template

Tags: html, laravel, hyperlink, routes, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel 5. In a specific Blade template, I have a link that looks like this:

```
<a href="/categories/1">{{ $category->category }}</a>
```

Normally on my localhost WAMP server, I can access my main page that has this link, like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp/laravel/public/
```

When you click the `<a>` link above, I want the link to simply go to:

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp/laravel/public/categories/1
```

Instead, it goes here:

```
http://localhost:8080/categories/1
```

If I don't include the leading "/" on `categories/1`. then it simply keeps adding `categories/1` to the url everytime I click it.  The first time it works, but the second time (and on) it of course says page not found.

What is the appropriate way to handle routing links in Laravel using the Blade templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<a href="{{ url('categories/1') }} ">{{ $category->category }}</a>
```

Comment: Hey that works perfect, thank you.  Marking you correct.

Comment: it will take the route after your project directory, like normal link. this url() helper of laravel will take you from public directory.